# Control values in numeric control

Tags: .net, vb.net

probably its easy but i cant figure out how to achieve that with effect. I have 3 numeric controls on my form. Values there could be either `1,2 or 3`. Assumption is each each of those three values can only appear once in one of those controls. So let's say i have

```
IntInputVariation1.value = 1
IntInputVariation2.value = 2
IntInputVariation3.value = 3
```

And now if someone change one of those values let say IntInputVariation2.value to 3 then IntInputVariation3.value has to be 2.

Hope you know what i mean.

When form is loading all controls are set from 1 to 3 like this:

```
IntInputVariation1.value = 1
IntInputVariation2.value = 2
IntInputVariation3.value = 3
```

and at this point user can change it...

So far i did this but still something is wrong.. Can you help?

I tried to save first state of my controls like this:

```
Private Class VariationPositionValues
        Public Shared First As String = "IntInputVariation1"
        Public Shared Second As String = "IntInputVariation2"
        Public Shared Third As String = "IntInputVariation3"
    End Class
```

and then below handler method i associated to to all of those there controls ValueChanged event:

```
 Private Sub IntInputVariation_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)



        Dim inputNumbControl As DevComponents.Editors.IntegerInput = CType(sender, DevComponents.Editors.IntegerInput)
        Dim NewValue As Integer = inputNumbControl.Value


        Select Case inputNumbControl.Name
            Case "IntInputVariation1"

                If IntInputVariation2.Value = NewValue Then
                    IntInputVariation2.Value = 1
                    VariationPositionValues.IntInputVariation1 = IntInputVariation1.Value
                    VariationPositionValues.IntInputVariation2 = IntInputVariation2.Value
                End If
                If IntInputVariation3.Value = NewValue Then
                    IntInputVariation3.Value = VariationPositionValues.IntInputVariation1
                    VariationPositionValues.IntInputVariation1 = IntInputVariation1.Value
                    VariationPositionValues.IntInputVariation3 = IntInputVariation3.Value
                End If

            Case "IntInputVariation2"
                If IntInputVariation1.Value = NewValue Then
                    IntInputVariation1.Value = VariationPositionValues.IntInputVariation2
                    VariationPositionValues.IntInputVariation2 = IntInputVariation2.Value
                    VariationPositionValues.IntInputVariation1 = IntInputVariation1.Value
                End If
                If IntInputVariation3.Value = NewValue Then
                    IntInputVariation3.Value = VariationPositionValues.IntInputVariation2
                    VariationPositionValues.IntInputVariation2 = IntInputVariation2.Value
                    VariationPositionValues.IntInputVariation3 = IntInputVariation3.Value
                End If

            Case "IntInputVariation3"
                If IntInputVariation1.Value = NewValue Then
                    IntInputVariation1.Value = VariationPositionValues.IntInputVariation3
                    VariationPositionValues.IntInputVariation3 = IntInputVariation3.Value
                    VariationPositionValues.IntInputVariation1 = IntInputVariation1.Value
                End If
                If IntInputVariation2.Value = NewValue Then
                    IntInputVariation2.Value = VariationPositionValues.IntInputVariation3
                    VariationPositionValues.IntInputVariation3 = IntInputVariation3.Value
                    VariationPositionValues.IntInputVariation2 = IntInputVariation2.Value
                End If
        End Select
    End Sub
```

**further discussion:**

```
  Select Case variationCount
                Case 1
                    nums = Enumerable.Range(1, 1).ToArray
                    nuds = {IntInputVariation1}
                Case 2
                    nums = Enumerable.Range(1, 2).ToArray
                    nuds = {IntInputVariation1, IntInputVariation2}
                Case 3
                    nums = Enumerable.Range(1, 3).ToArray
                    nuds = {IntInputVariation1, IntInputVariation2, IntInputVariation3}
            End Select

            ignore = False
```

then when code is accessing event on second try on this line:

```
If ignore Then Exit Sub
```

then get this error:  `System.IndexOutOfRangeException`

**Working solution for Plutonix to check :**

at form load got this:

```
 variationCount = BusinessLayer.SubKategorie_Variation.GetVariationCountBySubKategorie(AdvTreeSubKategories.SelectedValue)


        Select Case variationCount
            Case 1
                IntInputVariation1.MaxValue = 1

                nums = Enumerable.Range(1, 1).ToArray
                nuds = {IntInputVariation1}
            Case 2
                IntInputVariation1.MaxValue = 2
                IntInputVariation2.MaxValue = 2

                nums = Enumerable.Range(1, 2).ToArray
                nuds = {IntInputVariation1, IntInputVariation2}
            Case 3
                IntInputVariation1.MaxValue = 3
                IntInputVariation2.MaxValue = 3
                IntInputVariation3.MaxValue = 3

                nums = Enumerable.Range(1, 3).ToArray
                nuds = {IntInputVariation1, IntInputVariation2, IntInputVariation3}
        End Select

        ignore = False
```

and later i got this:

```
  If ignore Then Exit Sub

        ' dont do this while doing this ;)
        ignore = True

        '--Whho called
        Dim nud = CType(sender, DevComponents.Editors.IntegerInput)
        '--Other ctls, vals, remove the one the user changed
        Dim otherVals = nums.Except(New Int32() {nud.Value}).ToArray
        Dim others = nuds.Except(New DevComponents.Editors.IntegerInput() {nud}).ToArray

        ' set the first
        others(0).Value = otherVals(0)
        otherVals = otherVals.Except(New Int32() {others(0).Value}).ToArray
        If variationCount > 2 Then others(1).Value = otherVals(0)

        ignore = False
```

Comment: Is there really only 3 values?

Comment: yes, i think there is really easy way i cant find so far. one digit out of those 3 can appear only once within one of those controls. Would be easier if i could get old value in ValueChanged event but there isn;t.

Comment: Off the top of my head, you'd want to get the value of the changing one before it changes (maybe focus() event?) and save it, then, upon change, go through the other two and find the one that equals the new value and change that to the previous value of the one changed.  I think that would do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably ran into an issue of that event firing as a result of your code as well as when the user changes a value?  This uses standard `NumericUpDown` controls - the events and such may be different.

```
' form level vars: 
Private ignore As Boolean = True
Private nuds As NumericUpDown()
Private nums As Int32()
```

In form load, setup for however many there are:

```
variationCount = 3

nuds = {nud1, nud2, nud3}.Take(variationCount).ToArray()
nums = Enumerable.Range(1, variationCount).ToArray()

ignore = False            ' at the end
```

The ignore flag is so that you can ignore the event as a result of NET building your form.  It is also needed while setting the values.

```
Private Sub nud3_ValueChanged(sender As Object, 
          e As EventArgs) Handles nud3.ValueChanged, nud1.ValueChanged, nud2.ValueChanged
    If ignore Then Exit Sub

    ' dont do this while doing this ;)
    ignore = True

    ' who called
    Dim nud = CType(sender, NumericUpDown)
    ' other ctls, vals, remove the one the user changed
    Dim otherVals = nums.Except(New Int32() {nud.Value}).ToArray
    Dim others = nuds.Except(New NumericUpDown() {nud}).ToArray

    ' set the first
    others(0).Value = otherVals(0)
    otherVals = otherVals.Except(New Int32() {others(0).Value}).ToArray

    If variationCount > 2 Then others(1).Value = otherVals(0)

    ignore = False
End Sub
```

It might change one of them unnecessarily, its hard to tell with just 3, and with no `OldValue` to go by.

Comment: seems to be working - i didn;t mentione before but there is one more thing. I can have either one, two or three numer controls it depends on something when form loads. So i can have dynamicly one, two or three of those numerc controls - how to change your code to be ready on that situation? And to be honest can;t get this ignore variable for it is for.. :)

Comment: I think you'd just have to change `nuds = {nud1, nud2, nud3}` to only store what you are using.  The code isnt really tied to **three** controls.  well, change the int array too

Comment: look at my main post in "further discussion" - i am assigning control at form load, but i tested with two control cases and then i get system.indexOutOfRangeException

Comment: change the int array too  it is hard coded for three

Comment: did it look again in "further discussion but same problem.

Comment: `If variationCount > 2 Then others(1).Value = otherVals(0)`  - looking at other stuff too.  also be sure only 2 event handlers are hooked up

Comment: seems its working - i placed final code into "Working solution" in main post - can you please take a look once again as i am planning to deploy on production? And one more question as i can't understand why:  ' dont do this while doing this ;) (your comment.. What exactly is going on here ?:)

Comment: When you manually change the value for one of them it will fire the event again - you dont want to process those or you will get an endless flow of them.  So while that event code is running, the ignore flag prevents other change events from being processed.  You can shorted the setup code a little - thats not critical though.  I am trying to implement Steve's idea too - hard to capture the OldValue though

Comment: ye with this old value... wouldnt see that already built in.. a lot of work would be unnessecary :)

Comment: but this ignore will only be usefull if this would be running in background right (mean in task or whatever) then other user couldnt touch checkbox again during event already fired in other case it would be no usefull (in one thread) correct?

Comment: I got steves to work.  Since the code IN the ValueChanged event changes values it fires the event AGAIN.  Get rid of `ignore` and you'll see events fired when the form loads and you set the values and then again when your code in the event runs

Comment: sure it helped ! The Answer ! If something i come back again ! thank you PLutonix as always!

Comment: i think only your new input: nuds = {nud1, nud2, nud3}.Take(variationCount) as i tested raises range index error so i stayed as i put in main post

Comment: Thats working in mine - there should be a .ToArray on the end: `nuds = {nud1, nud2, nud3}.Take(variationCount).ToArray()`

Answer (score 0):

So I read your code and came up with this:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private _PreviousValues As New Dictionary(Of NumericUpDown, Integer)  
    Private _bIgnoreChange As Boolean = True

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()
        InitValues()
        SetPreviousVars()
        _bIgnoreChange = False
        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

    End Sub
    Private Sub IntInputVariation_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles IntInputVariation1.ValueChanged, IntInputVariation2.ValueChanged, IntInputVariation3.ValueChanged

        If Not _bIgnoreChange Then
            CheckForSwapValue(DirectCast(sender, NumericUpDown), IntInputVariation1)
            CheckForSwapValue(DirectCast(sender, NumericUpDown), IntInputVariation2)
            CheckForSwapValue(DirectCast(sender, NumericUpDown), IntInputVariation3)
        End If

        SetPreviousVars()

    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckForSwapValue(changedNUD As NumericUpDown, testNUD As NumericUpDown)

        If changedNUD IsNot testNUD AndAlso changedNUD.Value = testNUD.Value Then
            _bIgnoreChange = True
            testNUD.Value = _PreviousValues(changedNUD)
            _bIgnoreChange = False
        End If

    End Sub


    Private Sub InitValues()
        IntInputVariation1.Value = 1
        IntInputVariation2.Value = 2
        IntInputVariation3.Value = 3
    End Sub

    Private Sub SetPreviousVars()
        _PreviousValues(IntInputVariation1) = CInt(IntInputVariation1.Value)
        _PreviousValues(IntInputVariation2) = CInt(IntInputVariation2.Value)
        _PreviousValues(IntInputVariation3) = CInt(IntInputVariation3.Value)
    End Sub
End Class
```

I feel that the use of shared/static variables is unnecessary for what you are doing. A class level variable is all that is required if you are going to keep track of the old values in this manner.

Of course all this code is assuming that your are using winforms and NumericUpDown controls, but it would still work for other controls and in WPF by changing the control type.